# Seleniun Closing Tab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When i Run the code using the selenium, it open the google and search the word 'word',but after this, it close the chrome tab immediately

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 

driver_service=Service(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)

driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q').send_keys('word'+Keys.RETURN)
```

I want to keep the Tab Open after search the word

Comment: Did you tried `time.sleep()` ?

Comment: missing the `Keys` import? `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `detach`, if you have `driver.quit()` in your code that browser will close no matter if `options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)`
so code would be

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

[resources](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)
`detach     boolean     false`   
If false, Chrome will be quit when ChromeDriver is killed, regardless of whether the session is quit. If true, Chrome will only be quit if the session is quit (or closed). Note, if true, and the session is not quit, ChromeDriver cannot clean up the temporary user data directory that the running Chrome instance is using.

also can look at [this-bug](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10337)

Comment: Id doesent have driver.quit(), but now it worked with the detach.
Thank You,Merry Christmans

Comment: awesome! you too, Merry Christmas!